# Wrong axis order in geotools crs when reading from EPSG:4326

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, epsg

```
Map<String,Object> params = ...; // postgis params
DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
SimpleFeatureCollection collection=...;// collection to save
SimpleFeatureType schema = collection.getSchema();
dataStore.createSchema(schema); // but it creates with name "polygon"
MyUtils.save(collection,dataStore);  // saves to database
```

**schema before save:** `collection.getSchema().getCoordinateReferenceSystem().getCoordinateSystem().toString()` :

```
EllipsoidalCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
 AXIS["longitude", EAST],
 AXIS["latitude", NORTH]]
```

**postgresql table column definition:**

```
fid          serial NOT NULL
the_geom     geometry(Point,4326)
Name         character varying(93)
```

But when I read a collection from the same source, I face:
**schema after read:** `collection.getSchema().getCoordinateReferenceSystem().getCoordinateSystem().toString()`:

```
EllipsoidalCS["Ellipsoidal 2D CS. Axes: latitude, longitude. Orientation: north, east. UoM: degree",
 AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],
 AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],
 AUTHORITY["EPSG","6422"]]
```

The problem is that the x y coordinates are displaced in the schema but the point values are not.
I gues geotools cannot decode "EPSG:4326" correctly. `CRS.decode(string,boolean longitudeFirst)` guides to solution and a related question answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153996/geotools-crs-getaxisordercrs-getaxisorderepsg4326-returns-east-north-lon), but we can't change the collection.getSchema().
Problem of that question was creating a CRS with corrent axis order, but my problem is reading a feature collection with correct CRS.

Comment: Schema are immutable

Comment: iant that question is so different. Do not mark duplicate!

Comment: iant! I havn't got the solution. schema are immutable and I can't set CRS

Comment: You can edit the question to clarify why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: done! Problem of that question was creating a CRS with corrent axis order, but my problem is reading a feature collection with correct CRS.

Comment: the statement "I gues geotools cannot decode "EPSG:4326" correctly. CRS.decode(string,boolean longitudeFirst)" is what makes me think that this is the same as the duplicate I marked. Can you make it clear why this isn't so? or may be rewrite your question to make it clearer what you are trying to do?

Comment: the statement "I gues geotools cannot decode "EPSG:4326" correctly. CRS.decode(string,boolean longitudeFirst)" is what makes me think that this is the same as the duplicate I marked. Can you make it clear why this isn't so? or may be rewrite your question to make it clearer what you are trying to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26544/discussion-between-dariush-and-iant).